# Any suitable algorithm to solve?

Tags: java

I have to solve

```
for(n=1 to n<=<10^100){
p+=floor(e*n);

}
```

where e=Euler's constant;

Any suitable method or algo to solve this in very less time to find p ?

Comment: What are you solving with this? You aren't assigning anything or returning a value. Can you show us more of your code or explain your problem more precisely?

Comment: @Todd i have updated Q and I need value of p

Comment: @JacobG. What are u saying...

Comment: @JacobG.  BigInteger can store

Comment: You're attempting to iterate from 1 to a googol; it will never terminate.

Comment: @JacobG. take a look http://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/JtssGg

Answer (score 2):

According to [Sum of range of integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) you can use the formula n * ( n + 2 ) / 2. To multiply it with e just simply n * ( n + 2 ) / 2 * e. Because you can e put outside the brackets .. :)
e * sum(from i to n of i) = sum(from i to n of i * e)

Example for this:
1 * 3 + 2 * 3 + 3 * 3 + 4 * 3 = 3 * (1 + 2 + 3 + 4)

Comment: every time i have to take floor and then add .. so i cant take it out. :) i have updated Q

Comment: Why do you round it for every call? This is making the result more inaccurate

Comment: it is a need :)

Comment: for full code understanding  ide.geeksforgeeks.org/JtssGg

Comment: When you really want to floor it every time, you have no other choise of doing so with komplexity O(n) in my opinion .. But this will take forever xD .. ^^' If you dont care in accuracy so much you can use taylor or newton interpol. to approximate your function

Answer (score 0):

You can think of p this way

```
p = e + 2e + 3e + .... + (10^100)e
```

which means

```
p = (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (10^100) ) e
```

This term `(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (10^100))` equals `((10^100)*(10^100 +1))/2` using [partial sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

So final equation would be

```
p = ( ((10^100)*(10^100 + 1))/2 ) e
```

But in Java this would be very huge number, you need to use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), but as you will use Euler's constant which has decimal point, you will need [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead, initialize p as [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) object.

Here's the Java code to find `p` where `e = 2.71828`

```
BigDecimal power = new BigDecimal("10");
power = power.pow(100);
BigDecimal p = ( power.multiply(power.add(new BigDecimal("1"))) ).divide(new BigDecimal("2") ).multiply(new BigDecimal("2.71828"));
```

Comment: i already answered that .. He wants to floor the result of e*n every call. That means he has an jumping function and therefore he cant just do it that way